# How to protect an external volume with UWF on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, memory, external-hard-drive, usb-storage, uwf

I'm trying to use Unified Write Filter (UWF) to protect the memory of our embedded device that runs Windows 10. The problem is that it doesn't have any internal volume, and UWF won't work with USB flash drives. The only memory that is does have is an SD card that is connected to a USB port.

Is there a way to trick Windows 10 somehow into thinking that this SD card is some internal memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

If you first put the write filter on on a internal memory and then copy the image over to your removable device, it will have skipped the check of the removable bit on the SD card. Even more, it will never check this bit in the future, only the first time you activate the UWF

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a better way

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\uwfvol\Parameters\Static\Copy0\Volumes\0]
"VolumeName"="Volume{a9806337-736d-4119-898b-f532e82ca2ed}"
"DriveLetter"="c:"
"VolumeEnabled"=dword:00000001
"Binding"=dword:00000001
"PartitionStyle"=dword:00000001
"PartitionGuid"="{a9806337-736d-4119-898b-f532e82ca2ed}"
"FileExceptionsUserDefined"=hex(7):00,00,00,00
"NumFileExceptionsUserDefined"=dword:00000000
```

Insert this to Registry once (GUID must be UUID of YOUR disk not mine)
You can find it using "mountvol" command
Then restart and you are able to use "uwfmgr" in its usual way :)

Comment: Haven't tested it, but it looks like a solution that will work, knowing how poorly Windows prevents users of actually protecting it. When I come around testing it, I will accept this answer because it is a cleaner solution than the one I provided.